# Weird black marks showing next to certain plots in Python with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

While plotting some time series data I ran into an issue. With 2/15 of my plots I got these weird black marks showing up next to them in Jupyter Notebook.

[image: Black marks next to plots]

I tried re-running those specific plots in a normal .py file and I got the same results. So I tried plotting it in Excel instead.

[image: Excel plots]

Clearly, these plots are totally different. So something must be messing with the data when it runs through Matplotlib somehow. It looks inverted but not all of the peaks seem to be there. It is strange.

Unfortunately, I can't share my dataset. But I'm wondering if anyone has seen this before and could give me an idea of what is causing this. Because as I mentioned, 13/15 of my plots work perfectly as expected, and the code is the same.

Comment: Those "weird black marks" are the ticklabels. There are so many of them that they appear as one black "carpet". The mistake here is that you forgot to convert your data to numbers.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest As it turns out, some of the data in those two columns include imaginary numbers... Was not expecting that with this dataset. Thanks for pointing that out.